# Pine script How to return in many if-else statement in self declared function?

Tags: pine-script

What I want is to define a custom moving average function, which can choose one MA type among different MA types.

I tried it as:

```
ma_type = 'EMA'
ma(source, length) =>
    s = sma(source, length)
    e = ema(source, length)
    if ma_type == 'EMA'
        e
    if ma_type == 'SMA'
        s
    ...
```

However, this is not working!

I did not figure it out?
Can anyone correct me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the type a parameter of the custom function

```
f_ma(_source, _length, _type) =>
    _s = sma(_source, _length)
    _e = ema(_source, _length)
    float _ma = na
    if _type == "EMA"
        _ma := _e
    else if _type == "SMA"
        _ma := _s
    _ma


ma = f_ma(close, 20, "EMA")
plot(ma)
```

Can also be shortened as a ternary operation like this :

```
f_ma(_source, _length, _type) =>
    _ma = _type == "EMA" ? ema(_source, _length) : _type == "SMA" ? sma(_source, _length) : na
    _ma
```

Answer (score 2):

To shine some light on why it happens: each `if`-block returns some value, and the function returns the last value that was returned inside it. In your case, your first `if`-block returns the value of `e`, and your second `if`-block returns `na` because the condition in it is not true. Because of that, the function as a whole returns the last value returned inside it, i.e. `na`.

Using `else if` is one way to fix it, assigning a value to a variable and returning the variable is the other. For more examples, aside from the ones already posted above, you can see the source codes for built-in indicators MA Ribbon and Average True Range.